# ¿Cómo puedo utilizar la misma información en un segundo modal a través de AJAX?

Tags: javascript, html, mysql, ajax, nodejs

Tengo dos modales con id diferente, en los dos llamo la misma información, al dar clic en el botón del primer modal este funciona sin problemas con ayuda de AJAX, pero al querer dar clic en el segundo lo único que cambia es el id, la demás información no cambia, uso un AJAX y botón diferente para cada modal.

BOTON PARA LLAMAR EL AJAX:

```
<a onclick="verDato('<%= archivos.id%>')" 
   data-bs-toggle="modal"
   data-bs-target="#modalForm2" 
   class="btn text-light"
   style="background-color: rgba(27,158,29,255)" 
   data-id="1"><iclass="fa-solid fa-eye"></i>
</a>
```

AJAX:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        function verDato(registro) {
            var esperar = 2000;
            $('#registro').val(registro);
            $.ajax({
                url: '/ver-login-admin/' + registro,
                beforeSend: function () {
                    $('#ver-login-admin').text('Cargando..')
                },
                success: function (veregistro) {
                    console.log(veregistro);
                    Object.keys(veregistro).map(d => {
                        $('#' + d).val(veregistro[d]);
                        
                    })
                }
            })
        }
    </script>
```

Formulario en modal. En este caso al abrir el modal se actualiza el id y en consola me muestra los datos actualizados, pero por ejemplo "NO. OFFICIO", no cambia su valor en el modal:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="modalForm2" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="exampleModal" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog modal-xl">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <div class="container ">
                        <div class="card-body ">
                            <legend class="content mb-5 scheduler-border"> <span>VISUALIZACIÓN DE INFORMACIÓN DE
                                    OFICIO</span>
                                <button type="button" class="  btn  text-light mover" style="background-color: #6b6b6b"
                                    data-bs-dismiss="modal"><i class="fas fa-times"></i>&nbsp;
                                    Cerrar </button>
                            </legend>
                            <!--Primera fila-->
                            <% if (archivos) { %>
                                <input id="registro" name="registro" value="<%= archivos.id %>">
                                    <div class="row row-cols-1 row-cols-md-3">
                                        <div class="col">
                                            <div class="form-floating mb-4">
                                                <input type="text" class="form-control texto" id="no_oficio"
                                                    name="no_oficio" tabindex="3" placeholder="No. Oficio"
                                                    aria-label="No. Oficio" value="<%=archivos.no_oficio %>" disabled>
                                                <label for="floatingInput">No. Oficio</label>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                <% } %>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```